# Pact:Verify not picking up kafka config file. Same file gets picked up fine during consumer test run

Tags: apache-kafka, pact

We have implemented contract testing using message pact and directly accessing Kafka Topics for retrieving the messages from queues. Kafka topics can be accessed using authentication PLAINTEXT. So we have a separate LoginModule defined in a config file with username and password. When I do the test from consumer end it is picking up the correct config file and the scripts are running. But when I run pact:verify using the same setting in the script, LoginModule is not getting recognized and I get an error "unable to find LoginModule class". From pact side I am getting an error "Failed to invoke provider method". Have anyone faced such issues with using pact with kafka before please ?

Comment: Are you talking about this one? https://github.com/reevoo/pact-messages
If so, we are not currently supporting pact-messages as we have yet to finalize the base level tech with http/json.  This has been brought up in the past and is known within the Foundation, but we'd rather lock down the core technology before trying to tackle other message protocols/formats.

Comment: @J_A_X - if you post that again as an answer, I can upvote you :)

Comment: @TimothyJones done :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about this one? github.com/reevoo/pact-messages If so, we are not currently supporting pact-messages as we have yet to finalize the base level tech with http/json.

This has been brought up in the past and is known within the Foundation, but we'd rather lock down the core technology before trying to tackle other message protocols/formats.